# Should it be made mandatory to add a comment when downvoting questions?

Tags: feature-request

I've seen a number of downvotes for IMHO reasonable questions with no explanation on why?.

Surely the idea with the site is that people that want to learn about Ubuntu can ask questions that they can't themselves.

Would it would be more constructive to leave a comment on why its downvoted?   Perhaps we can all then vote on that comment to avoid people that just down vote questions which they personally don't like rather than answer them.

Answer (score 7):

I am one of the downvoters to this post, and I'll add an answer.

I'm against this because I believe the bad far outweighs the good in this case, from long debates to users getting attacked etc. If you want to drop a comment yourself, please do.

Another problem, what if another downvoter already posted a comment? Does every other downvoter need to post a reason for the downvote?

Take the following old post on meta.SE, for example, [A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required).

This post was downvoted 533 times as of this writing. Do you really want to read 533 comments to that post where most of them will be the same?

*I can also recommend checking the following posts https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/linked/2008?lq=1 and their answers. Almost all of them are about the same subject with good discussions.*

Comment: But just because you disagree with the question doesn't mean its not a valid question?.    Surely the point of the site is answer questions?.

Surely downvoting is for questions which do not meet the sites standards? 

Like in this case its a valid question but why should my reputation take a hit because you don't like the question?.

Comment: @SimonBanks votes on meta do not affect your reputation. An obvious reason for this is that on meta, everyone is encouraged to express their opinions, which reputation on main shouldn't depend on (people should be willing to express opinions they they think may be unpopular). Here, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement with opinions. While it can be difficult to interpret the meaning of votes at times, votes on meta generally have little to do with the quality of the post and way more to do with whether people think your idea is good, or your opinion accords with theirs.

Comment: Requiring comments on downvotes also removes all anonymity, which is a huge part of how voting works here, and opens users up to revenge voting.

Comment: **guiverc** always explains his downvotes and his votes to close. I have never seen anyone explode at him or attack him. I think he is one of the most respected persons on Ask. I think it is the tone in which the comment is made.