Is there a chatroom or a place where we can send our problems about 24.04?
I do not need the problem to be solved immediately, was thinking about getting more info about which logs, how to get them and where to send em.

AskUbuntu is not designed for interactive support or discussion. Great interactive help is available from UbuntuForums and on IRC, plus several unofficial community sites.  AskUbuntu is designed to easily locate high quality answers to clear questions. Ubuntu help is separate from the bug tracker.

Issues and bug reports need to be filed against Launchpad, there is no chat room on Ask Ubuntu for filing bugs here, as Ask Ubuntu is not where the developers track issues.
Note that 24.04 just released, and it's normal for bugs to happen.  Usually things're more stable by 24.04.1 which is when the normal upgrade paths open.
Refer to How do I report a bug? for how to bring issues to the attention of Ubuntu developers.  If they need additional information or logs, they'll ask for them in the bugs as comments.
If you just have general questions about "How do I do X?" in Ubuntu (where X is anything), then you may just want to post a question here on Ask Ubuntu.

And why did i get a -1 in asking a valid question? This is nuts!

@amar THAT I can't answer, but you should not take a single -1 as an offense. (And complaining about it doesn't help anything)

I would like to know why? that way I can understand and do better next time.

@amar here on the meta site, voting can work differently than on the main site. Here on meta downvotes are (also) being used with the meaning: "I don't agree with this initiative", or, "I don't think that this idea needs further development", and implicitly, "I don't want to invest more effort into explaining why". It's like a shortcut to democracy — which however indeed carries the risk to offend and alienate novice users, because it's unexplained. "Downvotes as mere disagreement with a proposal" are illustrated/demonstrated on e.g. this post: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19564/
